# How to prevent recreation of subscription filters during serverless deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I have a function(lambda) that is subscribed to cloudwatch logs of another function. The IaC for this looks like this:

```
ReadLoginLogs:
  handler: src/API.readFnLogs
  events:
    - cloudwatchLog:
        logGroup: /aws/lambda/project-xxx-api-${self:custom.stage}-function1
        filter: 'THIS_DATA'
```

The subscription filter is already created for this in AWS but during deployment, i get the following error:

```
Only 2 subscription filters can be configured per log group. There are subscription filters defined outside of the service definition for "/aws/lambda/project-xxx-api" that have to be deleted manually.
```

I'm not sure why serverless keeps attempting to recreate the subscription. How do I prevent serverless from attempting to recreate the subscription during deployment and just ignore creating it if it's already there?

Comment: How did you create this subscription filter in the first place? Was it created manually or during one of previous serverless deployments?

Comment: by a previous serverless deployment

Comment: Then it shouldn't redeploy it - please report it as a bug with reproduction steps here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Comment: I also got this issue, are you using serverless-plugin-split-stacks? Have you resolved this issue @AllanMogusu?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'serverless-plugin-log-subscription' to automatically create subscription filters instead of adding cloudwatch events for each log group. [serverless-plugin-log-subscription](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-log-subscription)